# Simulating Yarn Dynamics in Blender

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am trying to calculate the collision detection between the nodes of the single yarn, is that possible in blender for dynamic simulation of yarn, later I am supposed to use the Jersy model where I can calculate the sliding friction and contacts between nodes.

[image]

Comment: No, I don't think Blender physics engine is accurate or detailed enough to realistically simulate this type of thing

Comment: So what could be alternative for dynamic simulation of fabric and open source.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe look into "SOFA" 
(https://www.sofa-framework.org/)
which is a python based Physics engine for a wide range of things (including your problem i think)
I think there is even a previous version that was connected to blender so that blender uses SOFA as physics engine....

If you should find another solution, in blender or somewhere else, please post it! I'm interested in doing something similar myself!

Comment: I am already using SOFA, and that was a screenshot of my simulation, however, It didnot find a simulation for fabric of woven or knitted, currently, I am using it, but it seems not that easy, but this is only option.

Comment: yes, indeed there is a sofa blender plugin, I never used, I can check. Actually, in SOFA, they have only one simulation for a piece of garment, however, it sounds artificial for me, moreover, the SOFA has some limitation as it all builds linear system and fabric is highly nonlinear and viscoelastic material. Great! that you are interested in, definitely, I will keep this post updated.